# jfreechart dataset z-index (overlapping)

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have `jfreechart` with two datasets: `OHLCSeries` & `TimeSeries Line`.

I need the line chart to be on top (above the OHLC Series).

How is it possible to set overlapping of the dataset?

[image]

***Short question:* How to get the white line to the top (above OHLC series) ?**

Complete source of demo on [github](https://github.com/martinille/AnimatedCandlestick-demo1/tree/master/src).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the magic:

`chart.getXYPlot().setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);`

And result: while line is on top.

[image]